# Remove text on web page - following a String ">" until end of span

Tags: javascript, html

I interact with a web page at work that overloads me with redundant information of the form:

```
Important text 
Other important text 
>> Not important 1 
>> Not important 2 
>> Not important 3 
Other important text
```

I would love some javascript code that I can run in Tampermonkey that deletes all of the text in all spans starting from the first occurrence of `>` and ending at the end of the given span tag

Pseudo-code example:

```
var allSpanTags = document.getElementsByTagName('span');       

for(var thisSpanTag in allSpanTags){
   thisSpanTag.innerHTML.deleteStringBetween(index_of_first_">"_in_given_spans_inner_HTML  ,  index_of_end_of_innerHTML_of_this_span_tag);
}
```

The intricacies of the web beast are currently befuddling me on this project in JavaScript (not my native language). I'm also uncertain that I am even approaching the issue in the most effective manner.

Thanks!

Edit: I made my code apply specifically to spans with a certain className so that it would stop breaking other stuff on the webpage.

```
var allSpans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for(var i = 0; i < allSpans.length; i++) {
    try{
         if (allSpans[i].className.indexOf("textblock") > -1) {
             allSpans[i].innerHTML = allSpans[i].innerHTML.replace(/&gt;.*/g, '');
         }
    }catch(e){}
}
```

Comment: You can avoid the `for` loop entirely if you replace the `document.getElementsByTagName...` with `document.querySelectorAll('span.textblock')`.

Comment: Thanks! This is a cool and more elegant function than my className.indexOf haha. Could you explain... is it not the case that I would still need a for loop to loop through the resulting list from document.querySelectorAll in order to perform the replacement on each element?

Comment: I was meaning to say that the `for` loop in your edit would not need to iterate through all `span`s on the page, and the overall answer could still follow the format of my solution.

Comment: Just to be certain... even if the className of the target spans are "asdfasdf-textblock-asdfasdf" the query selector "span.textblock" will still grab this?

Comment: Hmm.. I did not think about that. So the `textblock` is not its own class, but is *inside* one of the class names?

Comment: Yeah, that may not have been clear but the web page has some really ugly class names (and is in Angular JS for that matter). I noticed all of the fields that i was interested in had the word "textblock" in their className (among a ton of other garbage) so I just did indexOf. I tested it with querySelector in jsFiddle and it doesn't work like that with querySelector. I learned a cool thing though, so thank you :)

Comment: In that case, look at my edit to my original answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('span')).forEach(
    a => a.innerHTML = a.innerHTML.replace(/&gt;.*/g,'')
);
```

```html
<span>Please delete after the > sign here!</span><br>
<span>Also, delete the sign > here!</span><br>
<span>Don't > forget > me!</span>
```

How about this solution?

EDIT: Now with [`document.querySelectorAll`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp) and the [`[*=]`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp) CSS selector!

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span[class*=textblock]')).forEach(
    a => a.innerHTML = a.innerHTML.replace(/&gt;.*/g,'')
);
```

```html
<span class="atextblock">Please delete after the > sign here!</span><br>
<span class="fun textblocks are not">Also, delete the sign > here!</span><br>
<span class="whytextblock why">Don't > forget > me!</span><br>
<span class="muahahahaha">> But not > here!</span>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great!

Comment: @Render I'm glad to help! :)

Comment: Just pointing out that the function signature, `function(a,b,c)` isn't necessary. You can just reference `a` and run `a.innerHTML = ...` and that'll work. No need to reference the index or the array reference itself.

Comment: @wcarroll Good point, I edited it myself to make it even shorter with ES6 arrow syntax.

Comment: @wcarroll tbh I was confused by that myself when I looked at Stardust's solution. Thanks for the clarification!